# How can i change the fill color of a CALayer in Core Graphics?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-graphics, calayer

I have a shape, a CALayer, which I want to add core graphics effects to. Right now, I want to keep it simple and change the fill colour of it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you just want to change the color of the whole layer you can use:

```
layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor];
```

if you have a more complex shape like a path to fill, you need to overwrite the layer's `drawInContext:` with sth like this:

```
- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    //...
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
    //...
}
```

See [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html) for more info.

Comment: To complete @Tobi answer, if your layer inherits from `CAShapeLayer` no need to subclass it you can use the `fillColor` property.

Answer (score 1):

```
shape.fillColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

`[[UIColor redColor] setFill]` is what you're looking for, I believe.

I don't have Xcode open atm, but that should be the right method if you're trying to fill a path.